# Is there any alternative to TimeZone.getTimeZone() in Java?

Tags: java, timezone

Is there any alternative to `TimeZone.getTimeZone()` in Java, since `getTimeZone()` is `synchronized`, causing my program/application to scale down.

```
public static synchronized TimeZone getTimeZone(String ID) {
       return getTimeZone(ID, true);
 }
```

Comment: You might consider this one, alternative for Java Date and classes. http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: Or @VictorG.S., even better [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310). (quoted from your link)

Answer (score 4):

You don’t want to use `TimeZone` in 2018. Modern example:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Dawson_Creek");
```

The date and time classes from Java 1.0 and 1.1 — `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat` and also `TimeZone` — are long outdated and were never well designed. `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API has been included with Java since Java 8 (out four years ago). It replaces them and is much nicer to work with.

If you thought you needed a `TimeZone`, for example for setting the time zone of a `Calendar`, this class too has been replaced (they all have, as I said). Instead use the modern `ZonedDateTime`:

```
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime
            .parse("2018-06-22T01:23:31.615464+11:00[Pacific/Guadalcanal]");
    ZonedDateTime converted = dateTime.withZoneSameInstant(zone);
    System.out.println("2018-06-22T01:23:31.615464 in Guadalcanal = " + converted);
```

Output:

> 2018-06-22T01:23:31.615464 in Guadalcanal =
>   2018-06-21T07:23:31.615464-07:00[America/Dawson_Creek]

It may of course occur that you need an old-fashioned `TimeZone` object for a legacy API that you either cannot change or don’t want to change just now. In that case use the conversion that Lino pointed out in another answer:

```
    TimeZone oldfashionedTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(zone);
    System.out.println(oldfashionedTimeZone);
```

> sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Dawson_Creek",offset=-25200000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=58,lastRule=null]

If your problem is that the synchronization of `TimeZone.getTimeZone(String)` is slowing your program down, I am wondering how many `TimeZone` objects you are creating? With just 600 available time zone IDs (in my Java 10), I don’t think you need that many. I still clearly recommend `ZoneId` over `TimeZone`, but if the creation takes too long, caching them might be a better option?

### Question: But what if I am using Java 6 or 7?

No big problem. `java.time` works nicely on Java 6 and 7 too. Only the conversions to the outdated classes are different, for example:

```
    TimeZone oldfashionedTimeZone = DateTimeUtils.toTimeZone(zone);
```

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

What about `TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId)`. Which is not synchronized:

```
// JDK 8 source
public static TimeZone getTimeZone(ZoneId zoneId) {
    String tzid = zoneId.getId(); // throws an NPE if null
    char c = tzid.charAt(0);
    if (c == '+' || c == '-') {
        tzid = "GMT" + tzid;
    } else if (c == 'Z' && tzid.length() == 1) {
        tzid = "UTC";
    }
    return getTimeZone(tzid, true);
}
```

See the following example:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.of("Europe"));
```

Comment: Great. And if you can use the Java 8 `ZoneId`, there is no reason why you should want to use the old and outdated `TimeZone` class too. `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, offers all the functionality that you need.

Comment: @OleV.V. I didn't even thought about that one, but you're right. You can create another answer or feel free to edit a comment into mine if you wish, because nobody should use the old `Date` API any more :)